# Block/mosaic type homepage with heavily interactive menu

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, theming

I wanted to know if this was possible to do for a Drupal website like this website has the main navigation how it works and interacts with the main content layout. http://goo.gl/HQ4P8H

What modules must be used to do that? I am okay if it needs .js for the 'effects', but I want to understand how it works when loading new stuff from navigation while in the same page without refresh.

Also when you hover on blocks it gives various/interactive content, menus and links. How is that done on Drupal? Is it something can be pulled of from Views and then applying jQuery to output content in that way while on hover?

So in overall I wanted to know if this can be achieved without custom php coding, because I am not programmer, if it's only .js .css and modules that would be great to know which ones.

Cheers.

Comment: I think it is better to describe what the menu does and what you like about it. Some day in the future, tn.gov might get a new design and the fancy mechanic is gone.

Comment: Regarding the menu, you should do a google search for "drupal mega menu" or "drupal mega dropdown". There are a number of modules to potentially help you with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a module to do that, but you have to customize it. It have the animation option using filter, probably you can try to use that filter as menu or change that filter like menu using CSS.

[Views Quicksand](https://drupal.org/project/views_quicksand) see the [Demo](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) and [website](http://www.lightrains.com/portfolio) using Drupal.

> Quicksand is a JQuery Plugin that provides a nice animation for
>   filtering or reordering lists of content. Views Quicksand integrates this effect into Views. Therefore it provides a views style-plugin, which allows you to alter most settings the quicksand plugin provides.

Answer (score 2):

As Bala mentioned, Views quicksand will work, however if you want them to interlock with different shapes and sizes, you'll likely need to use something like Jquery Masonry alongside quicksand.  There's an [API and a set of sub-modules](https://drupal.org/project/masonry) already built for drupal.